# Connecting 74HC165 to 74HC595

Tags: shift-register

This is a rather noob and potentially silly question. I am planning to allow the user to randomly connect the 8 output pins of the 74HC595 to any of the 8 input pins of the 74HC165 shift out and shift in registers. I am trying recreate a digital Enigma machine. I am wondering if #1 and #2 from http://www.rugged-circuits.com/10-ways-to-destroy-an-arduino/ will allow me to add some extra protection to the input and output pins to the shift registers.

Comment: How much do you trust your user? :) What sorts of errors do you expect them to make?

Comment: Well in theory, the user is just me, and the errors could be:
- Connecting two input pins together
- Connecting two output pins together
- Drop a 9V battery on the inputs and outputs.

Comment: If users are interacting with the pins, you will want to consider ESD protection. Look up TVS diodes.

Answer (score 1):

If your purpose is simply to be able to detect which output is connected to which input, you should be able to add a resistor up to 100K or perhaps more in series with each input or output without affecting operation.  If you want somewhat more protection, you could add some small capacitors on the inputs to the 74HC595.  Adding capacitance will significantly increase the time required for signals to propagate; the approximate time in seconds will be twice the resistance value in ohms, times the capacitor value in farads (or if you prefer, resistance value in megohms times the capacitor value in microfarads).  Using 100K resistors and 0.1uF capacitors would mean that you'd have to wait about 0.02 seconds for signals to propagate, but your board would be extremely robust.  Reducing the caps to 0.001uF cap would cut the time by a factor of 100 but your board would still be pretty robust (connecting to AC120 would probably not faze it).  If you want to be robust against AC240, that could be achieved if you use half-watt resistors but otherwise leave the circuit as-is.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you have to use few resistors at the output of 74HC595 and at the inputs of 74HC165 like follows;

```
                              +5V
                               \
                               /
                               \  10K ohm
                               /
                               |
                               |
                   110 ohm     |                 110 ohm
74HC165 input -----/\/\/\/\----|---o-------o----/\/\/\/\-------- 74HC595 output
                                   *       *

* are connectors on PCB for connections to users
```

Answer (score 0):

Masterleous' suggestion is a good one to protect the HC outputs when several are shorted together. Wrt the HC inputs, I would be most concerned about ESD damage with lot of plugging/unplugging. In order to protect from that, I would consider a small zener diode at each input (connected from input to ground after the 110Ω resister suggested by Masterleous), with Vz~4.5 V.